# How to embed img from external hosting in Django Template?

Tags: html, css, django, django-models, imgsource

I am trying to use Gdrive image url in django template

Django Template

`<p>{{post.scr}}</p><li class="post"><a href="{{post.href}}"><img src="{{post.src}}" alt="{{post.alt}}" width=auto height="300px"><h4>{{post.name}}</h4></a></li>`

Django Model

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    catname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    href = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    scr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

But actual url of scr is scr="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xyz"

There is a error in loading in image from external source (gdrive img link)

```
<p>https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xyz</p>
<img src(unknown) alt="#img3" width="auto" height="300px">
```

How to pass a external img url as src url in Django

Comment: Check [Django field reference - UrlField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#urlfield)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

models.py

**src = models.URLField(max_length=300 )**

in template

```
<img src="{{post.src}}" alt="{{post.alt}}">
```

While adding object in src field:

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=IMAGE_ID

Comment: I had tried changing URLField in models.py still the result is same error @madhan-umk

Comment: can u post , template and src filed value?